# Storm zkRoot is not created

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

> I was want to create the storm-kafka topology, but the spout read the data from kafka repeatable, and I found that the zkRoot was not created. Does anyone know the reason?

```
String brokerZkStr = "192.168.2.125:2181";
String topic = "topic_kafka";
String zkRoot = "/stormffbkafka";
String id = "kafka-word";
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
BrokerHosts hosts = new ZkHosts(brokerZkStr);
SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts, topic, zkRoot, id);

spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
spoutConfig.zkServers=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("192.168.2.125"));
spoutConfig.zkPort = 2181;
KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig);
```

Comment: Did you find out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "/" from zkroot

`String zkRoot = "stormffbkafka";`

Thanks.